# Keyboard layout missing after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: gnome, keyboard, 22.04, keyboard-layout, language-support

On 20.04 I used to have 3 keyboard layouts: `German`, `German(neo, QWERTZ)` and `Japanese (Mozc)`.
After upgrading to 22.04 I still have both German options in the login screen (I still don't have Japanese, but I still don't need it). But after login `German(neo, QWERTZ)` vanishes and I can only choose between `German` and `Japanese (Mozc)`.

In 22.04 neo and neo+QWERTZ come built-in. Before I think I had build my own neo+QWERTZ layout but the timestamps in /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules are all either `2021-06-08 22:20:40` or `2021-08-18 11:26:23` which suggests that the upgrade did the last write on them. (I could not have manually edited two files in the same second).

When I try to add `German(neo, QWERTZ)` under Activities -> Settings -> Keyboard -> Input Sources I cannot select anything with `neo`. Even with `Other` there are only `German (<country>)` and `<other language> (German)`.
When I try to enable `Show Extended Input Sources` in Gnome Tweaks -> Keyboard & Mouse it is already shown as enabled (disable, enable does not work).

How can I get my two German keyboard layouts back?

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.input-sources sources` gives
`[('xkb', 'de'), ('ibus', 'mozc-jp')]`

**Update**
Gunnar's: Edit II, solved it. `German (Germany)` is not a layout but indeed a folder that needs to be clicked [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**German (Neo, QWERTZ)** is considered to be an "exotic" layout. To access it on Ubuntu with GNOME:

- Install the `gnome-tweaks` package, unless it's already installed
- Open *Tweaks* and select *Keyboard & Mouse*
- Enable *Show Extended Input Sources*
- Log out and log in again

Now you can add **German (Neo, QWERTZ)** in *Settings -> Keyboard*.

*Edit:*

Oops.. I now see that you already tried that. But that is still how to do it, and if it doesn't work there is some problem with your configuration.

*Edit II:*

Or possibly it's a very common misunderstanding with respect to the GNOME UI for adding input sources: Assuming that you have the German locale generated, you should not look for additional German layouts in "Other". Instead click "German", which will open a sub menu with multiple German layout variants.